# Finally Photo.SE eligible for the Generalist badge

Tags: discussion

The Generalist badge (provide non-wiki answers of 15+ total score in 20 of top 40 tags) required that the top 40 tags have at least 200 questions each, which is a requirement some may not have known about.  It's taken awhile, but we finally got there!

Comment: Indeed, got the badge yesterday!

Answer (score 3):

If you're curious as to your own progress towards this shiny silver Internet sticker, check out [this Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/photo/query/448989/generalist-badge). Find your UserId by looking in the URL of your profile ([like, mine is 1943](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm?tab=profile)), and plug it in to see your progress.

Comment: you can use the url http://photo.stackexchange.com/users/current

Comment: Cool; that will redirect to the current logged-in user's profile, and then you can see the ID # in the URL.